# RMAN not working in Crontab

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rman

I have a cronjob scheduled to be executed every morning at 1.25 am. The script suppose to delete the archive logs created in Oracle DB for the previous day. But it is not executing as expected.  But when I execute it manually in the command prompt it executes and delete the archive logs as expected. I hope the problem is when the script connecting to RMAN as a cronjob. But I dont know how to solve it pls help me on this. Following are the things I use

The OS is Susei linux

cron is scheduled as below

```
25 01 * * * /x01/rman_backup/mahesh/logde.sh
```

Contents in logde.sh

```
ORACLE_HOME=/x01/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
ORACLE_SID=sec
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

/x01/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/rman cmdfile=/x01/rman_backup/mahesh  /logdelete.rcv
```

contents in the  logdelete.rcv

```
connect target /
run
{
delete archivelog all completed before 'trunc(sysdate)';
crosscheck archivelog all;

}
exit;
```

Comment: not sure, but is this any help: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2240186

Comment: Add the "LOG" rman command line option to your script so that you capture the error.

Answer (score -1):

You must use EXPORT to set environment variables, otherwise environment will not set

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/x01/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
export ORACLE_SID=sec
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Also i would suggest to use in which shell you want to execute by mentioning sh or ksh

```
25 01 * * * sh /x01/rman_backup/mahesh/logde.sh
```

Please check below URL for more info
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-shell-scripting